# Is there an algorithm/process for finding all modular forms of a given level and weight?

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms

Given a congruence subgroup $\Gamma<SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and a weight $k$, we have the space $M_k(\Gamma)$ of modular forms for $\Gamma$ of weight $k$. In every example I've seen, one is able to produce a basis of this space via known constructions, pushing/pulling from other modular curves, Eisenstein series, taking products, etc.

My question is whether there is a precise theorem stating that one is guaranteed to find generators of $M_k(\Gamma)$ via these processes (or other, explicit methods), or whether there may be forms which can't be found in this way?

If there is a cleaner statement, I'm happy to restrict to $\Gamma_0(N)$, $\Gamma(N)$ and $\Gamma_1(N)$ rather than an arbitrary congruence subgroup. Any references would also be much appreciated.

Comment: William Stein's *Modular Forms: A Computational Approach* probably has what you want: https://wstein.org/books/modform/stein-modform.pdf

Comment: Thanks! That seems like exactly what I want, hopefully there’s a clean statement in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of modular symbols (described in William Stein's [book](https://wstein.org/books/modform/stein-modform.pdf)) typically works very well in practice.

Another technique that one can use is the [Eichler-Selberg trace formula](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/google/es-trace-sl2z/HeckeOpTraces-en.pdf) (and variants for generic level), which can be used to explicitly compute a single "trace form" of given weight, level, and nebentypus. Applying various Hecke operators to the trace form will give a spanning basis for the space of modular forms, which can then be diagonalized by the Hecke algebra (but not, interestingly *just* using the Hecke operators) to get an eigenbasis.

More generally, when we computed classical modular forms for the [LMDFB](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/), we used techniques described in our paper [Computing classical modular forms](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.04717). This paper also summarizes various useful theorems in both the modular symbol approach and the trace formula approach.